# How to sum data dynamically

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like in picture below:

[tables example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHmXl.jpg)

I change price of one product. Then I need to update total_price in table two for all customers.
How to update total_price in table two in one statement for all the customers?

Comment: don't post data sample as image (only) post the sample as tabular text ..

Answer (score 0):

You could use update with join

```
update table_two t2
inner join (
    select id_customer, sum(price) tot
    group by id_customer
) t1 t1.id_customer = t2.id_customer 
set t2.total_price  = t1.tot
```